# How to grab all events of freeswitch in nodejs

Tags: node.js, freeswitch

Am newbie in node.js and would like to grab [all events types](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15139379).

In this case i already did my homework.I found from far [this one](http://freeswitch-users.2379917.n2.nabble.com/Javascript-Outbound-Event-Socket-Linger-Command-td7530943.html).

In link, Continuosly throwing below error.

Error :

```
TypeError: esl.createCallServer is not a function
```

I am expecting : If any call has been started and forward to the gateway.So on the realtime would like to get gateway name in node.js to check which gateway is using

Might be possible,I understand is not correct way but below also one more try to achieve this but that not giving me gateway information.

```
call_handler = require('seem');
const esl = require("esl");
const port = 4041;

    const server = esl.server(call_handler).listen(port);
    server.listen(port, function() {
        console.log("Server listening for connection requests on socket localhost:"+port);
    });
    esl.client(call_handler).connect(4050);
    server.on("connection", function(chunk) {
        console.log("Connection has been established");
        chunk.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log("Channel Park info");
            
            var data_string = data.toString();
            var data_arr= data_string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\r").replace(/\n/g, "\r").split(/\r/);
            var data_array= JSON.stringify( data_arr );
            console.log(data_array);
            chunk.end();
            });
    
    });
```

Node.js server have port is `4050.`

From Freeswitch dialplan, I am executing below line

```
<action application="socket" data="127.0.0.1:4041 full"/>
```

Expected Output :

Whenever call is bridge on any gateway then after and before complete call am able to get bridge line from node.js
Also parameters which are added in dialplan as set/export that also must be get on node.js

Anyone like to share some hints for this problem ?